# Get vscode auto-import to work for lodash

Tags: visual-studio-code, lodash, auto-import

I use lodash every day while programming and so find it extremely frustrating that it doesn't auto import like most of dependencies. Does anyone have any sort of hack that can get it to work?

For example, I'd love to just start typing `reduce` and have it pop up as one of the auto-importable options: 
[image: reduce not auto-importing from lodash]

Currently that isn't the case. I've opened a number of issues in vscode and lodash to try to get this solved (https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/4062 & https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63239) but haven't gotten any help so far. I'm hoping that other devs might have struggled with this and found some workaround.